# Load assembly and change source, is it possible and how?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, on-the-fly

I'm writing [.NET On-the-Fly](http://fly.sf.net) compiler for CLR scripting and want to implement next idea: there is a template file with C# code, I want to read it, create an assembly, load it and amplify source on-the-fly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [CompileAssemblyFromSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx).  I've done something simliar in the past, where I augmented some scripts with static class wrappers so they could easily be called.  You can [see it (or steal from it) here.](http://trac.assembla.com/plugintoolkit/browser/trunk/Pluto.Scripting/Implementation/ScriptEngine.cs)

To do this, just load your template, add your extra amplifications to the code, and compile it in one shot.

---

If you want to modify an existing assembly, you will need to use something like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).  It allows you to load and modify as assembly at runtime.  There is a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/reflexil.aspx?display=Print) article using Reflexil, a GPL product based on Cecil, which may help you get some ideas...

Comment: Thanks for link, it's very useful! And so you mean, that only one way is to change source code before compilation, not after?

Comment: No.  However, you can probably use something like Cecil (http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to inject into your assembly.  I'll update to include that.